# How to automount an smb server after connecting to a specific IP address with the OpenVPN Connect app?

Tags: macos, mac, monterey, smb

I am running MacOS Monterey 12.7.1. I am connecting to a VPN server using the Openvpn Connect app (The official openvpn app for mac os). After accessing that server via OpenVPN Connect, I mount an SMB share from that server onto my mac desktop. I do this in one of 2 ways,

From the terminal:

```
open smb://my_smb_username:'my_smb_password'@192.168.1.1/my_smb_shared_folder
```

or From MacOS Finder:

```
Go > Connect to Server > smb://192.168.1.1/

Enter username and password in the MacOS Popup. SMB Now Mounted.
```

I would like to consolidate these tasks, so that any time I connect to the OpenVPN server from my mac client, the SMB Share mounts automatically, and unmount automatically after disconnecting from the VPN server.

How can I go about doing this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the OpenVPN Connect application allow to run a script after a connection goes up or down?

Comment: No i don't think it does.